# Contact List with Multiple Selection using CheckBoxes

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-listview, android-contacts

I am trying to create a List in which I take the Contacts I have in my android phone, with CheckBoxes and Images. For now I am just trying to get the contacts on the list with the checkbox.

Code is as Follows :

Problems I am facing :
1) Unable to create ViewHolder Properly

2) Unable to populate contacts into a adapter

3) Unable to retrive images from contacts

main.java

```
package com.example.curs;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState );
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);






       my_custom_adapter adapter = new my_custom_adapter(this, // Context.
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, // Specify the row template
                // to use (here, two
                // columns bound to the
                // two retrieved cursor
                // rows).
                mCursor, // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
                // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
                new String []{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those
                // columns.
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});


        setListAdapter(adapter);


}
    private Cursor getContacts() {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                sortOrder);
    }


}
```

my_custom_adapter.java

```
package com.example.curs;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class my_custom_adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
        private Context context                     ;
        //ArrayList<String> elements                 ;
        private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked      ;
        Cursor c;
        String contact_id;
        String contact_name[];
        String []from;
        int to1;
        int to2;
        String elements;

    public my_custom_adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String []from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

       // set_checked(false);
    }

    /*
        // AS EVERY TIME LISTVIEW INFLATE YOUR VIEWS WHEN YOU MOVE THEM SO YOU NEED TO SAVE ALL OF YOUR CHECKBOX STATES IN SOME ARRAYLIST OTHERWISE IT WILL SET ANY DEFAULT VALUE.
        private void set_checked(boolean is_checked)
        {
            for (int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                itemChecked.add(i, is_checked);

            }
        }

    */

        //THIS IS SIMPLY A CLASS VIEW WILL HOLD DIFFERENT VIEWS OF YOUR ROW.
        static class ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView tv;
            public CheckBox cb;
            public ImageView iv;
        }


        public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

        View rowView = convertView;
        View view = null;
        if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
              Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, null);


        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        rowView.setTag(holder);


        holder.cb
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {


                      /*  Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        */
                    }
                });
      view.setTag(holder);
      holder.cb.setTag(c.getPosition());

    } else {
      view = convertView;
      ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).cb.setTag(c.getPosition());
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.tv.setText(c.getString(c.getPosition()));
    holder.iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(),c.getPosition()));

    //holder.cb.setChecked(c.getPosition().isSelected());
    return view;
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

inflated_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp" />




    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:padding="15dp"/>


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267859/how-to-obtain-the-checked-rows-in-a-custom-view-list/17268392#17268392. example with names and phone number add get image part by modifying the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509178/getting-a-photo-from-a-contact. to get image from contact.

Comment: Sir I do want CheckBoxes?

Comment: did you check the first link?

Comment: Thanks sir , will check this code !